# Popover from another html file with css

Tags: php, html, css, popup, popover

I'm currently struggling with an issue regarding my login system. I got 2 files - index.php and login.php. I got a link named "Login" on my index page and a login form on my login page. I would like to make the "Login" link on my index page responsive, so when you hover over it, the login form will appear and so you can simply log in. I have watched some tutorials on youtube but none of them was actually about loading the data from another html file. I have spent hours trying to figure this out but haven't found any solution. Is there please any possibility how to make it just with html and css? Thanks a lot for any advice.

```
 This is the part of my html code from index.php file: 
  <section>
              <div class="logs">
                  <div class="login-popover">
                  <a href='login.php' target='_blank'>Login</a>
                  </div>
                  <a href='logout-sql.php'>Logout</a>
                  <a href='signup.php' target='_blank'>Sign Up</a>
              </div>
  </section>    



 This is the part my html code from login.php file:



  <?php
          if(isset($_SESSION['account'])) {
              $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "eshop-tech");
              $id = $_SESSION['account'];
              $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id= $id");
              $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
              echo 'You are logged in as ' . $row['username'];
    
              echo '<div class="logout">
                      <h3>Logout</h3>
                      <form action="logout-sql.php" method="post">
                          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Logout"><br>
                      </form>
                  </div>';
  
              } else {
              echo '<span class="login">
              <h3>Log In here</h3><br>
                      <form id="inputs" action="login-sql.php" method="post">
                          <div class="form-inputs">
                              <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br>
                                  </div>
                          <div class="form-inputs">
                              <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br>
                                  </div>
                              <div class="forget">
                                  <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
                              </div><br>
                          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br>
                          <a href="signup.php" class="createacc">Sign Up</a>
                      </form>
                  </span>';               
    
          }
      ?>
 
 
 
 
 and this is my css: 
 
  .login input {
      width: 6vw;
  }
        
  .Sign-up input {
      width: 20vw;
  }
         
  .forget, .createacc {
      display: block;
      text-align:center;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: Arial;
      color: #fff;
         
  }
 
  .login h3 {
      text-align:center;
  }
 
 
 
  .login-popover {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
      text-decoration: underline;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
 
  #inputs {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 4rem;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 0.5rem;
      padding: 1rem;
      width: 280px;
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0.5s, bottom 0.5s;
  }
 
  #inputs .form-inputs {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;   
  }
 
  .form-inputs input {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
      border: 2px solid #eee;
      font-size: 1rem;
      outline: none;
  }
   
  #inputs::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      border: 1rem solid;
      border-color: #fff transparent transparent;
      bottom:-2rem;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      width: 150px;
  }
     
  .login-popover:hover #inputs {
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      bottom: 3.5rem;
  }
```

Comment: Why not just add a login form in a pop over to index.php directly? That form can then be posted back to login.php to complete the process

Comment: If you absolutely have to load from a different file, put it into its own html file. Don't put it into a larger file trying to separate it own.

Comment: _"I have watched some tutorials on youtube but none of them was actually about loading the data from another html file."_ - that could have to do with the fact that what you are trying to achieve, doesn't have much to do with the keyword "responsive" in the first place.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks a lot! This actually helped but how do I post the form back to login.php, please?

Comment: All HTML forms can have an `action` attribute which specifies the URL the form data should be submitted to - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attributes_for_form_submission . You already know this, because you've already put `action="login-sql.php"` into the HTML login form you showed us above.